# ArcMap to ArcGIS online/Collector

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, android, arcgis-collector

I am trying to figure out the workflow from ArcMap to ArcGIS online/Collector. I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2, using a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (Android 4.3, JB)

I am able to use the `share as` option in ArcMap and then see my map on ArcGIS online, but I cannot see it in the Collector.

Comment: Have you shared the map with a group in your organization?

Comment: Yes I have shared the map in my organization.

Answer (score 4):

I've only done this a couple of times, so I'm far from an expert.

There's a bit more to getting it into collector.   Your layers need to be shared as feature layers in ArcGIS online, and they need to be editable.

I don't think you can share an mxd from ArcMap and have it available in Collector.   The way I did it was to import a shapefile to Online, then publish it (from within ArcGIS Online) as a feature layer.  From there I used that feature layer to build a web map in Online, which showed up in Collector.

Comment: I use this method and correct 'Shared as Feature Layer editable' is the way http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/android/create-maps/create-and-share-a-collector-map.htm

Comment: after publishing on the app go to your organization webpage
(arcgis online) and sign in. Then Search for your published map

Comment: Your workflow worked great, thanks.  I think an issue I was having was that I was initially using ArcGIS 10.0. then I upgraded to 10.2.2 and the workflow was different for the 2 versions.  ArcGIS 10.0 does not have a "share as" option.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever done this on a desktop because I have never needed to create a map on a tablet. But, on ArcGIS 10.2.2 Desktop you have to:

1) Sign in and select 'File' --> 'Share As'-->'Service...'.

2) Select 'Publish a service' from the list on the first page. **Click OK**.

3) Select 'My Hosted Services...' from the drop down menu under 'Choose a Connection'. **Click Continue**.

4) On the Service Editor page: in the 'Capabilities' tab Check 'Feature Access' to turn it on and uncheck 'Tiled Mapping' to turn it off.

5) In the 'Feature Access' tab, allow all operations* by checking the boxes beside them.

6) Fill out the required information on the 'Item Description' tab.

7) **Click 'Publish'** in the upper-right corner.

Once this finishes, log on to AGOL in your web browser.

1) Find the data set that you uploaded and add it to a new map.

2) Save the new map.

That's it, you can now open your new map in Collector.

Collector accesses maps, not data files, in ArcGIS Online. So, if you want to access the feature class you just uploaded using the 'Share As' tool, you have to add the feature layer(s) to an AGOL map after the feature class has been uploaded.

- In the 'Feature Access' tab under 'Operations allowed:'

Create allows new features to be created in collector.

Delete allows existing features to be deleted in Collector.

Query allows features to be queried in ArcGIS Online based on attributes.

Sync allows you to work offline -- with some work needed beforehand.

Update allows users to update features in collector.